# redirection using ajax with javascript variables passed in the url.

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect, web2py

I am doing the following to pass the javascript variable from the view to
the controller:

default/rough2.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<p id="demo">

</p>
<script>

var x=document.getElementById("demo");
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
geolocation();
})

function geolocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

} else {
x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lon= position.coords.longitude;

ajax('{{=URL('default','rough3')}}'+'?lat='+lat+'&lon='+lon,[],':eval');
}


</script>
```

rough3() function

```
def rough3():
    lat1=request.vars.lat
    lon1=request.vars.lon
    ...........................
    .......................
```

But it is "not getting redirected to rough3.html".I do not understand
why?Any help is highly appreciated!

Regards,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a redirect via Javascript, just set `window.location` (an Ajax call does not load a new page in the browser window):

```
window.location = '{{=URL('default', 'rough3')}}' + '?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon;
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of Ajax is that it makes the HTTP request **without leaving the current page**.

If you want to go to a new URL, then assign it to `location`, don't use Ajax.

Comment: I am passing javascript variables as vars.If I use document.location="{{=URL(....vars={}}}"..then it has the python part.Python gets executed on the server even before the page is loaded while javascript gets the result from the server in response to some user event.Hence I have to use ajax.Thanks for the reply anyways.What else can be done?